# User.py Exception Type: TypeError Exception Value: 'Manager' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

Hello I have a little problem in Django, I created a database and now I want to print the queries of this, so I have in my user.py file the following code

```
def user(request):
user_list = User.objects
user_dict = {'user_data': user_list}



return render(request,'AppTwo/User.html',context=user_dict)
```

here i get the following error: 
User.py Exception Type: TypeError Exception Value: 'Manager' object is not iterable.

To fix this, I need to change the code to this:

```
def user(request):
user_list = User.objects.order_by('first_name')
user_dict = {'user_data': user_list}



return render(request,'AppTwo/User.html',context=user_dict)
```

but I can not understand why the simple adding of order_by('first_name'), casts the object to a list? Why do I need this? I have trouble to understand, maybe somebody could help me and explain to me what is happening here.
Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2):

`User.objects` doesn't return a result as a [queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/), it's just the reference to the *manager* associated to the model.

A *Manager* is a class object which provides all the methods available to create queries and filters on the model.

You only obtain a queryset when you call these [methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#methods-that-return-new-querysets) like `all()`, `filter`, `order_by`...

A manager can even be overridden to provide special filters automatically, or you can also add extra managers in your model to use different filters/queries depending on the context.

---

Documentation :

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/
- https://djangobook.com/advanced-models/#leanpub-auto-managers

Comment: you can add this link [methods-that-return-new-querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#methods-that-return-new-querysets)

Answer (score 0):

we need to iterate over the query result so to do that we have to give objects.all() or objects.order_by('name')